# stprtool box matlab mex

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I am trying to use the kernel function of `stprtool box` in `Matlab`. As it is a c file, I used the `mex` function to link it. However, I encountered the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_arg1", referenced from:
  _mexFunction in kernel.o
"_dataA", referenced from:
  _mexFunction in kernel.o
"_dataB", referenced from:
  _mexFunction in kernel.o
"_dim", referenced from:
  _mexFunction in kernel.o
"_ker", referenced from:
  _mexFunction in kernel.o
"_kernel", referenced from:
  _mexFunction in kernel.o
"_kernel_id", referenced from:
  _mexFunction in kernel.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

mex: link of ' "kernel.mexmaci64"' failed.
```

`arg1` to `kernel_id` are some variables in the `kernel.c`. Would you have any idea to fix this problem?